# C++ template alias (using) in specific places

Tags: c++, scope, using, template-aliases

I need to use type aliases via `using` (or any other method) in situations like this:

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if< /*HERE*/>::value
f (...) {};
```

Where I wrote `HERE` there are long and more than one types defined inside structures, and instead of writing `typename <very long templated struct dependent on T>::type` I want to write a shortcut.

And I encountered this in more situations like template specializations and suffix return type syntax.
So Is there any way of using `using` (no pun intended) in places between the first line `template <...>` and the struct/class or function?.

I have tried using `,` (comma) something like `(using X = ... , /*actually using X*/)` without success.

What worked was a global scoped `using`

```
template <class Iterator>
using DT = typename DereferenceType<Iterator>::type&;
```

but I don't want global scope, I want the scope to be just for the template I use it. And I don't want to write `DT<Iterator>`, just `DT`.

Needless to say macros or any preprocessor directives are out of the question.

---

Real life example:

```
template <class Iterator, class GetCompValue, class SortOrder = Ascending>
typename std::enable_if<
    IsDereferenceable<Iterator>::value &&
    IsCallableLike<GetCompValue,
                   typename DereferenceType<Iterator>::type&(
                      typename DereferenceType<Iterator>::type&)>::value &&
    IsSortOrder<SortOrder>::value, void>::type
RadixSortLSDByteOffsetIter(Iterator first, Iterator last,
                           GetCompValue get_comp_value, SortOrder = kAscending) {
```

Here I want a shortcut for `typename DereferenceType<Iterator>::type&` something like:

```
template <class Iterator, class GetCompValue, class SortOrder = Ascending>
// using DT = typename DereferenceType<Iterator>::type&;
typename std::enable_if<
    IsDereferenceable<Iterator>::value &&
    IsCallableLike<GetCompValue, DT(DT)>::value &&
    IsSortOrder<SortOrder>::value, void>::type
RadixSortLSDByteOffsetIter(Iterator first, Iterator last,
                           GetCompValue get_comp_value, SortOrder = kAscending) {
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++14 will solve your problem by introducing *variable templates*:

```
template <typename T>
T one_half = T(1) / T(2);

template <typename A, typename B>
bool is_base_of_v = std::is_base_of<A, B>::value;
```

Usage:

```
std::cout << one_half<double> << "\n" << is_base_of_v<Foo, Bar> << "\n";
```

So you'll be able to make your `HERE` into a boolean-valued variable template.

---

Unrelatedly, another way to clean up your traits is to get rid of the `typename ...::type`, like so:

```
template <typename C, typename T = void>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<C, T>::type;
```

Now you can use:

```
template <typename T> enable_if_t<my_condition<T>> f() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thank you, the clean up suggestion is very helpful. However even variable templates, if I understand correctly, need to be declared outside (globally), so there is no way for a declaration to be viewable only on the return type declaration of a function.

Comment: @bolov: That's right, but a) those templates may be sufficiently general to make sense globally, in a library of their own, or b) you can put those into a `detail::` subnamespace within your current namespace to make sure it doesn't collide with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just alias by defining new types?

```
struct alias : long-long-typename {}
```

Comment: because of global scope. It is the same as global `using`. I want a shortcut to work just inside a templated function/struct, but not in the body, but in the return type