# How to avoid duplication on template function return type?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a way to avoid duplication and improve readability on template functions return type ?

Here is an example

```
template <typename FunctionType>
std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<FunctionType, MyClass*>>,
    std::optional<std::invoke_result_t<FunctionType, MyClass*>>
> CallIfValid(MyClass* instance, FunctionType func)
{
    using InvocationType = std::invoke_result_t<FunctionType, MyClass*>;
    if (instance != nullptr)
    {
        return func(instance);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::optional<InvocationType>();
    }
}
```

Notice how `std::invoke_result_t<FunctionType, MyClass*>` ends up duplicated twice in return type, and also a third time in method body.

Any suggestions or trick I am not seeing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/120405-specialized-template-function-results-duplicate-symbols.html

Comment: Link refers to template specialization, where a method is specialized to behaves differently on certain types. EnableIf has a similar role, by allowing method specialization to exist or not depending on type traits.
My question is actually on how to avoid / reduce type duplication on return types and parameter types.

Comment: closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800658/c-template-alias-using-in-specific-places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. In my personal opinion there isn't a good real solution, not for the general case. But there are some mitigations/workarounds you can employ. In your example you can add a default template parameter. Also since you specified the return type, you don't need to repeat the type in the return expression:

```
template <typename FunctionType, class InvocationType  = std::invoke_result_t<FunctionType, MyClass*>>
std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_void_v<InvocationType >,
    std::optional<InvocationType >
> CallIfValid(MyClass* instance, FunctionType func)
{
    if (instance != nullptr)
    {
        return func(instance);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::nullopt; // if you want to be explicit (I personally prefer this)
        // return {}; // if you want to be terse
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use a alias template to avoid repeating `InvocationType` without adding a template parameter.

Comment: @DavisHerring can you elaborate? I am afraid I don't understand.

Comment: Given `template<class T> using non_void_opt=std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<T>,std::optional<T>>;`, the return type of `CallIfValid` can be written just as `non_void_opt<std::invoke_result_t<FunctionType,MyClass*>>`.

Comment: @DavisHerring : Interesting ! I never thought of that ! I prefer to restrict type scope to method, but your suggestion is nice in case of reusage.